# Multiple java threads on a 2-core Mac - Slow

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, operating-system

I've been writing the following code for my OS course and I got some weird results. The code creates x threads and runs them concurrently in order to multiply two squared matrices. Every thread will multiply Number_of_rows/Number_of_threads rows of the input matrices.

When running it on a 1024X1024 matrices, with 1...8 threads, I get that the fastest multiplication happens when using only one thread. I would expect that a MacBook pro with i5 processor (2-cores) will utilize the two cores and that will yield faster results when using two threads. 
Running time goes from about ~9.2 seconds using one thread, ~9.6 seconds to 27 seconds using 8.

Any idea why this is happening?

BTW, A few things about the code:

a. Assume that both matrices have identical dimensions and are square.

b. Assume that number of threads <= number of rows/columns.

```
public class MatrixMultThread implements Runnable {
    final static int MATRIX_SIZE = 1024;
    final static int MAX_THREADS = MATRIX_SIZE;
    private float[][] a;
    private float[][] b;
    private float[][] res;
    private int startIndex;
    private int endIndex;


public MatrixMultThread(float[][] a, float[][]b, float[][] res, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.res = res;
    this.startIndex = startIndex;
    this.endIndex = endIndex;
}


public void run() {
    float value = 0;
    for (int k = startIndex; k < endIndex; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                value += a[k][j]*b[j][i];
            }
            res[k][i] = value;
            value = 0;
        }
    }
}


public static float[][] mult(float[][] a, float[][] b, int threadCount){

    // Get number of rows per each thread.
    int rowsPerThread = (int) Math.ceil(MATRIX_SIZE / threadCount);
    float[][] res = new float[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];

    // Create thread array
    Thread[] threadsArray = new Thread[threadCount];
    int rowCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
        threadsArray[i] = new Thread(new MatrixMultThread(a,b,res,rowCounter, Math.max(rowCounter + rowsPerThread, MATRIX_SIZE)));
        threadsArray[i].start();
        rowCounter += rowsPerThread;
    }


    // Wait for all threads to end before finishing execution.
    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
        try {
            threadsArray[i].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("join failed");
        }
    }
    return res;
}


public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Create matrices and random generator
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    float[][] a = new float[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];
    float[][] b = new float[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];

    // Initialize two matrices with initial values from 1 to 10.
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            a[i][j] = randomGenerator.nextFloat() * randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
            b[i][j] = randomGenerator.nextFloat() * randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
        }
    }
    long startTime;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mult(a,b,i);
        System.out.println("Total running time is: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " ms");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It means that your solution is not as parallel as you think it is. You should check to find out how multiple threads can work in parallel and then output results. Also your input should be large enough so that you get benefit of multithreading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly a bit of logging helps. I did logging for this and found out a bug in your logic.

Here is the log

```
Starting execution for thread count: 1
Start index: 0
End index: 1024
Starting execution: MatrixMultiplier: 0
Ending executionMatrixMultiplier: 0
Total running time is: 6593 ms


Starting execution for thread count: 2
Start index: 0
End index: 1024  <------ This is the problem area
Start index: 512
End index: 1024
Starting execution: MatrixMultiplier: 1
Starting execution: MatrixMultiplier: 0
```

Your first thread in all iterations is performing whole multiplication everytime. That's why you are not seeing results. Figure out the bug.

Comment: Narendra Pathai thank you! You're write, If I used a bit more logs it would have helped me. Got the bug and fixed it. Works fine now thanks!

Comment: If you are starting out as a programmer. Just remember that Logging and Documenting your code are the two best friends of yours! Logic comes secondary to that when you become a professional.